# Как побороть ошибку "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть у меня такой нативный [модуль](https://github.com/skycocker/react-native-sfsafariviewcontroller) для React Native, который открывает Safari View Controller:

RCTSFSafariViewController.m:

```
#import "RCTSFSafariViewController.h"

@implementation RCTSFSafariViewController

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"SFSafariViewControllerDismissed" body:nil];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openURL:(NSString *)urlString params:(NSDictionary *)params) {
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;

  SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:safariViewController];

  [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  safariViewController.delegate = self;

  if ([params objectForKey:@"tintColor"]) {
    UIColor *tintColor = [RCTConvert UIColor:params[@"tintColor"]];

    if([safariViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredControlTintColor:)]) {
      safariViewController.preferredControlTintColor = tintColor;
    } else {
      safariViewController.view.tintColor = tintColor;
    }
  }

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
      [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendDeviceEventWithName:@"SFSafariViewControllerDidLoad" body:nil];
    }];
  });
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(close) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
    [rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  });
}

@end
```

RCTSFSafariViewController.h:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@import SafariServices;

@interface RCTSFSafariViewController : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

В общем случае всё работает хорошо (на моих устройствах и в симуляторе), но при этом у достаточно большого числа пользователей случается краш:

```
Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x14e3bd20> was mutated while being enumerated.' was thrown while invoking openURL on target SFSafariViewController with params ( "https://example.com", { } )
```

Всё бы было понятно, если бы здесь использовался какой-нибудь массив, или хоть что-то было явно enumerated. Но здесь ничего такого нет. И у меня появилась идея, что виноват во всём dispatch_async, потому что если его убрать, то воспроизвести такую проблему не удаётся (с dispatch_async приложение можно на некоторое время оставить открытым в симуляторе и при вызове будет появляться эта ошибка).

При этом убрать dispatch_async нельзя: сам Safari View Controller и приложение начинают после вызова нещадно тормозить.

Подскажите, в чём конкретно может быть проблема и как её устранить?